# How to refer Knockout.js objects and array of objects in right context

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I can´t seem to get this right: http://jsfiddle.net/dPyQy/4/

I want to collect the tags I am entering in the input field for saving. I need to reference the Textbatches as a SelectedText as in RL I need to be able to choose among Textbatches.

```
var Textbatch = function (data,tags) {
    var self = this;

    self.TextbatchId = data.TextbatchId;
    self.Title = ko.observable(data.Title);
    self.Text = ko.observable(data.Text);
    self.TextTags = ko.observableArray(tags);

    function createTypeComputed(tagType) {
        return ko.computed(function () {
            return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.TextTags(), function (item) {
                return item.Type() == tagType;
            });
        });
   }

   self.managerTags = createTypeComputed(0);

   self.removeTag = function (tagToRemove) {
       self.TextTags.remove(function (item) {
           return item.Id == tagToRemove.Id;
       });
   }
}
```

Struggling with the contexts and the objects and everything. I want the chosen tags listed beneath the input-field, and then the debug to show the updated object.

Any help highly appreciated. Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

`managerTags` evaluates to an array, but you're using it in a `text` binding which is expecting it to evaluate to a string.

How do you want to display it? As an HTML list (use a `foreach` binding to loop over the tags), or as a comma (or something)-separated string (use `join` on it)?

To get a comma-separated string, change `createTypeComputed` to

```
function createTypeComputed(tagType) {
  return ko.computed(function () {
    return ko.utils.arrayMap(      
      ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.TextTags(), function (item) {
         return item.Type() == tagType;
      }),
      function (item) {
        return item.Name();
      }).join(',');
    });
}
```

Note that if you can count on using an ES5 browser (anything but IE<9) you can simplify the function for the computed to

```
    return self.TextTags().filter(function (item) {
        return item.Type() == tagType;
      })
      .map(function (item) {
        return item.Name();
      })
      .join(',');
```

Comment: I´d like a comma-separated string.

Comment: So modify your `computed` to return a string by using the filtered array's `join` method.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot see that (alone at least) helping. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Thanx. I have included that in an updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dPyQy/5/ , but still I have the same problems with printing out the managerTags (see "Local managers"-string and second debug-string in fiddle.

Comment: My mistake: forgot to extract the `Name` field from the objects; see updated answer.

Comment: Great! :) Nearly there. Now I only need to get the "Local Selected" to update with tying in the input-field…
Updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/PM3QS/3/